# How to Handle Keyboard After Reload Table View?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

After reload tableview, Inside Textfield keyboard is not showing properly .How can i fix That keyboard properly.

This is My code,
Here, I am Getting Firebase Images

```
let queue = OperationQueue()

queue.addOperation {
    if let urlString = nammaApartmentVisitor.getprofilePhoto() {
        NAFirebase().downloadImageFromServerURL(urlString: urlString,imageView: cell.image_View)
    }
}

queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()

if isActivityIndicatorRunning == false {
    cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
} else if (isActivityIndicatorRunning == true) {
    cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Here reload the tableview ,This is code

Comment: @objc func imageHandle(notification: Notification) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isActivityIndicatorRunning = true
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

Comment: Passing Notification Center

Comment: Do not post comments. [Edit] your question with all relevant details.